# Using a button to move to a certain ID on a page

Tags: html

So I'm making a website (suprise, suprise) and I have a button on the top of the page, and when I click it, it does nothing. I am wondering how to fix it.

The button

```
<button class="Learn-Link" href="#VideoSlide">Learn How
<div class="Learn-Triangle"></div>
</button>
```

And the part I want to travel to

```
<div class="Slide" id="VideoSlide">
<!--More code here, but not relevant-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button` doesn't have an href attribute you need to add an `a` tag inside your button

```css
#VideoSlide{
  position: relative;
  top:1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<button class="Learn-Link" ><a href="#VideoSlide">Learn How</a>
<div class="Learn-Triangle"></div>
</button>
<div class="Slide" id="VideoSlide">
<!--More code here, but not relevant-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger button by using `javascript`
**Eg:-**

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
```